# Adding bullets to Jquery - Jquery closest

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('.add-bullet').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('textarea').val(
    $(this).closest('textarea').val() + '\u2022'
  );

  return false;
});


   <div><a href = "#" class = "add-bullet">Add bullet</a></div>
   <textarea name =""></textarea>
```

For some reason, when I click on add bullet, its not adding to the textarea, meaning the closest is not working. What can I do?

Comment: share your html also, because without it we won't able to find the relationship between the `add-bullet` and textarea. Any way I don't think `closest` will work here since `add-bullet` may not be a child of textarea

Comment: You may be looking for `.next()` or `.prev()`

Answer (score 0):

likely a scoping problem with "this".

you will want to pass the onclick event in your function, like

```
$('.add-bullet').click(function(e) {
  $(e.target).closest('textarea').val(
    $(e.target).closest('textarea').val() + '\u2022'
  );
  return false;
});
```

try that.

Comment: I don't think so because it doesn't look like `add-bullet` is a child of a textarea

Answer (score 0):

Here the `textarea` is the next element of the `add-bullet`'s parent

So you need to use [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$('.add-bullet').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next('textarea').val(function(idx, value){
        return value + '\u2022';
    });
    return false;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Mvdre/)